# How to Parse the given JSON Specially Which contains Array using ObjectMapper

Tags: swift3, objectmapper

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class MemberActivityCollection: Mappable
{
    var TotalRows : Int = 0
    var MemberActivityList : Array<MemberActivity> = Array()
    var MemberID: Int = 0


    init(){ }   
    internal required init?(map: Map) { }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        MemberActivityList      <- map["MemberActivityList"]
        TotalRows               <- map["TotalRows"]
        MemberID                <- map["MemberID"]
    }
}

class MemberActivity: Mappable
{
    var ActivityID: Int = 0
    var fk_MemberID: Int = 0
    var ActivityDate: String!
    var ActivityFrom: String!
    var ActivityTo: String!
    var AvgPace: String!

    init(){ }
    internal required init?(map: Map) { }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        ActivityID          <- map["ActivityID"]
        fk_MemberID         <- map["fk_MemberID"]
        ActivityDate        <- map["ActivityDate"]
        ActivityFrom        <- map["ActivityFrom"]
        ActivityTo          <- map["ActivityTo"]
        AvgPace             <- map["AvgPace"]
    }
}
```

> Please Note : The MemberActivityCollection Class has Array of MemberActivity Class

Need to Parse the JSON as MemberActivityCollection

```
{
  "TotalRows" : 16,
  "MemberActivityList" : [
    {
      "fk_MemberID" : 47,
      "ActivityID" : 29,
      "ActivityFrom" : "18:30:00",
      "ActivityTo" : "14:30:00",
      "AvgPace" : "3.00"
    },
    {
      "fk_MemberID" : 47,
      "ActivityID" : 26,
      "ActivityFrom" : "01:07:46",
      "ActivityTo" : "05:07:00",
      "AvgPace" : "5.00"
    },
    {
      "fk_MemberID" : 47,
      "ActivityID" : 35,
      "ActivityFrom" : "09:30:00",
      "ActivityTo" : "04:15:00",
      "AvgPace" : "0.06"
    }
  ],
  "MemberID" : 47
}
```

Using the following code to map the json to object of MemberActivityCollection Class

Am I declaring the property MemberActivityList wrong way??

The whole idea is to map the json in MemberActivityCollection class so that one of its property ("MemberActivityList") can hold the detailed data

To Achieve that I wrote following lines of code and not getting the desired output (As mentioned in the above line).

```
let objMAC : MemberActivityCollection = Mapper<MemberActivityCollection>().map(JSONObject: jsonData)! //Datatype of jsonData variable is JSON
```

The above statement throws error message that '**EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0**'

Please explain the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: why are you using mapping use NSdictionary and save values in key pair

Comment: @Subhojit Well it is a healthy practice to map the JSON Data with some local class/ subclass even though dictionary object is available. Suppose a key is altered on the server side, and If the json is parsed to local class we just need to modify the mapping clause, and need not to take care about the whole application. There might be other benefits of doing so.

Comment: Any updates on this?